# Javascript function program

Tags: javascript

Could Someone Pls Help Checkout this? I still can submit this even after passing all five test.

Question

According to the description of R-rated films: Children under 17 require an accompanying parent or adult guardian (age 21 or older) and adults 25 years and under must show ID. And children under the age of 6 are not allowed in after 6:00pm.

Deadpool is an R-rated movie.

Write a JavaScript function named canIWatch that will take age as a parameter.

If the age is less than 6, return You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.

If the age is 6 or more but less than 17, return You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.

If the age is 17 or more but less than 25, return You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some ID.

If the age is 25 or greater, return Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!.

If the age is invalid, return Invalid age.

Unittest

```
describe('canIWatch tests', function () {

  it('Should return the appropriate message for age less than 6', function () {
    expect(canIWatch(5)).toEqual('You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.');
  });

  it('Should return the appropriate message for age less than 17', function () {
    expect(canIWatch(15)).toEqual('You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.');
  });

  it('Should return the appropriate message for age less than 25', function () {
    expect(canIWatch(20)).toEqual('You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some ID.');
  });

  it('Should return the appropriate message for age above 25 than 6', function () {
    expect(canIWatch(30)).toEqual('Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!');
  });

  it('should return an appropriate message if provided age is invalid', function () {
    expect(canIWatch(-1)).toEqual('Invalid age.');
  });
});
```

Here is my solution:

```
function canIWatch(age) {

    if(age > 0 && age < 6) {

        return "You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.";
    }

    else if(age > 6 && age < 17) {

        return "You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.";
    }
    else if(age > 17 && age < 25) {
        return "You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some ID.";
    }
    else if(age > 25 && age < 200) {

        return "Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!";
    }
    else {
        return "Invalid age.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: what happens when age is exactly 6, 17 or 25?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between "age is more than 6" and "age is 6 or more"?

Comment: You don't even need to check the bottom of the age range. The previous `if` statement already handles the case where the age is below the range, you just need to check the top of the range.

Comment: What part works, and what part specifically doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
else if(age > 6 && age < 17) {
```

to:

```
else if(age < 17) {
```

and similarly for the other `else if` statements.

When the age is exactly 6, it won't match the previous `age < 6`, and it won't match `age > 6 && age < 17`, either. If you want to check for age at least 6, it should be `age >= 6`. But you don't need to do that, because the previous `if` already runs when the age is less than 6, so you're guaranteed that age is at least 6 when you get to this `else if`.

You also need a case at the beginning for age less than 1, which is invalid. You don't need the check at the end for age less than 200.

```
function canIWatch(age) {

    if (age <= 0) {
        return "Invalid age.";
    }

    else if(age < 6) {

        return "You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.";
    }

    else if(age < 17) {

        return "You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.";
    }
    else if(age < 25) {
        return "You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some ID.";
    }
    else {

        return "Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!";
    }
}
```

Comment: This pop out an error which says: " canIWatch tests should return an appropriate message if provided age is invalid
Expected 'You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.' to equal 'Invalid age.'."

Comment: You need a check for age less than 1. I've updated my answer with the ful code.

Comment: else if(age >= 6 && age  < 17)  {    ,  else if(age  >= 17 &&  age <25) { ...and so on.  Thanks man, appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect answer to the Andela question based on test.

```
function canIWatch(age) {

    if (age <= 0) {
        return "Invalid age.";
    }

    else if(age < 6) {

        return "You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.";
    }

    else if(age < 17) {

        return "You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.";
    }
    else if(age < 25) {
        return "You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some ID.";
    }
    else if(age >= 25) {

        return "Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!";
    }
    else {
        return "Invalid age.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function canIWatch(age){

    if (age <= 0) {
        return "Invalid age.";
    }

    else if(age < 6) {
        return "You are not allowed to watch Deadpool after 6.00pm.";

    }
    else if(age < 17) {
        return "You must be accompanied by a guardian who is 21 or older.";
    }
    else if(age < 25) {
        return "You are allowed to watch Deadpool, right after you show some          ID.";
    }
    else  {
        return "Yay! You can watch Deadpool with no strings attached!";
    }
  }
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine for the home study test above. Note that invalid age refers to a negative age hence giving the test for IF (age<=0) takes care of this requirement while the else statement takes care of age 25 and above. I have tested this code it works